# macOS: burning a 'raw' image to a DVD/BR

Tags: macos, encryption, dvd, burning

I'm playing with different options to have encrypted backups of my data on optical supports (DVD/BR). I'm working with macOS (Mojave+). At the moment I'm trying the Veracrypt way and created an encrypted image with the same size of a DVD+R DL; the next step should be burning this image to the optical disk, but `hdiutil` fails because it wants to recognise the image:

```
hdiutil burn "my image"
hdiutil: burn: "my image" not recognized - image not recognised
hdiutil: burn failed - image not recognised
```

Is there any way to force `hdiutil`? Reading the man page it looks like it can't. Any other tool? Command-line preferred, as this should be integrated into a workflow.

Thanks.

Comment: "the veracrypt way" is actually quite vague. It appears to be "make a veracrypt container file on an HDD and then burn it based on the first google hit. This is not an image, you would need to create an image that contained the container file e.g. `hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o image.iso /path/to/source`

Comment: The "veracrypt way" is not vague, neither is "googled", as I have experience with Truecrypt/Veracrypt since a long time and used this approach to encrypt a number of things including magnetic disks, USB keys and SSDs. The only new thing in my approach is the optical target. Basically I could have not mentioned veracrypt at all, being the question clearly defined in the title, "burning a raw image" that is not ISO.

Comment: Just to make things clear - my question is basically the same as this one, with the exception that I need to work with macOS: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360099/write-arbitrary-data-to-dvd-in-linux

Comment: aren't `cdrecord` and `mkisofs` (from that thread) available for macos? ( cdrtools ) or have you ruled that method out?

Comment: AFAIK, they are no more supported on macOS; but I could be wrong. I'd be happy if somebody described his experience with those tools on recent macOSes. If possible, I'd like to use native macOS tools because Apple is progressively applying stricter and stricter security checks on the operating system, so it's easy that you discover that a non official tool doesn't run any longer on a new macOS.

Comment: Why don't you just use a standard Apple encrypted .dmg, which you can then just copy/burn as a file to anything.

Comment: I prefer to use Veracrypt as it is vendor independent and I consider it more reliable.